# uwp- debug on local dosen't work

Tags: c#, uwp

I was running the app in debug mode on simulator. After a while, the debug mode can't take HTTP requests on local (remote server works fine). I am not sure if it's because I started to work with simulator, but that was the only thing I can see that was different from last time. The problem is that it doesn't work now even in local machine. I get the exception:

> system.PlatformNotSupportedException in system.Private.ServiceModel.dll.

Maybe some setting was changed unintentionally?

Comment: It doesn't even build?

Comment: it's build but throws exception after it's try to connect to local server.

Comment: @yeafit check if all permisions a set in the App Manifiest, you need Internet, and something related to networks